# Cygwin/X and Windows Subsystem for Linux with Unix domain socket

Tags: cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cygwin-x

[Graphical apps in WSL, e.g., gedit or xterm and so forth, can connect to Cygwin/X through TCP](https://superuser.com/questions/1180005/cygwin-x-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux). Since [current WSL (partially) supports AF_UNIX](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/), is it possible to connect to Cygwin/X through Unix domain socket ?

`sudo mount --bind /mnt/c/cygwin64/tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix` or `sudo ln -s /mnt/c/cygwin64/tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/` under WSL seems not to work... `DISPLAY=:0 xterm` still reports `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0`

Comment: Not that it helps specifically.. but I use VcXSrv and it works fine for this.  I have no problem running xterm or anything else.  Perhaps I don't understand the problem.

Comment: try with `DISPLAY=:0.0` https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-local-apps.html

Answer (score 3):

The way Cygwin emulates Unix sockets is to produce a fake socket file and perform handshaking over TCP, as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086038/what-mechanism-is-used-by-msys-cygwin-to-emulate-unix-domain-sockets).  These fake socket files aren't real Unix socket files and can't be used by WSL, since it doesn't know anything about their format.

Windows itself now [supports `AF_UNIX` sockets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/), but these [can't be used by both Windows and Linux software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/).  If you can convince Cygwin to use real `AF_UNIX` sockets instead of its fake socket formats and you don't have any other clients on the Windows side, then you *might* be able to make things work, but I am skeptical.

As far as I know, WSL 2 is not likely to help, since in that case, the sockets are entirely in Linux itself and wouldn't be shared with Windows.